# How can I tell from which branch the push is coming from?

Tags: git, automation, githooks

I'm trying to limit pushes to the `master` branch by only allowing `push` commands that come from the `test` branch.

How can I tell from which branch the `push` is coming from?

Comment: "only allowing `push` commands to come from the `test` branch" doesn't really make much sense. Branches, like most of Git, are distributed. Your `test` branch and mine may be completely and utterly separate, having no commits in common at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, at least not with conventional methods in receive and update hooks.  Pushes don't "come from" anywhere in particular: the hooks simply get a list of reference-names and SHA-1 values.

The `pre-receive` and `update` hooks get a chance to approve or disapprove of each request to change label `refs/whatever` to some new SHA-1 (in your case you'd want to see if the label is specifically `refs/heads/master`).  (The difference between `pre-receive` and `update` is that the former gets the entire list on stdin, with old and new SHA-1 values, while the latter gets the updates one at a time as arguments, i.e., it's called once for each to-be-updated ref.  A single `push` can push many ref updates.  The `pre-receive` hook can then verify the set as a whole, but can only say Yea or Nay to the update-as-a-whole; if it says Yea, the `update` hook can verify each update individually and say Yea or Nay to each one individually.)

The `post-receive` hook gets called after all updates are done, with a list of "ref *`X`* used to point to *oldsha* and now points to *newsha*" changes.

In all cases, there's no source information, just the raw SHA-1—which makes sense since whoever is running the `push` command can do:

```
git push remote 1234567:refs/tags/foo
```

for instance, to create a new tag pointing to object `1234567` without actually having any corresponding tag in their own repo.

To make this sort of thing work, you can refuse pushes to `master` entirely, and alter the process: users push to some other branch (or even a different repository), and once the result is vetted, the now-vetted commit is brought in to `master` by some other means (manual or automated-merge-from-success).

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to use gitk:  http://git-scm.com/docs/gitk